# InventoryClickEvent gets fired multiple times

Tags: java, bukkit, spigot

I have an abstract GUI parent class handling a click event.

```java
public abstract class GUI implements Listener {

    private final Inventory inventory;

    public GUI(Player player) {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, NPCs.getPlugin());

        ItemStack fillerItem = new ItemStack(getFiller());
        ItemMeta fillerItemMeta = fillerItem.getItemMeta();
        fillerItemMeta.setDisplayName("");
        fillerItem.setItemMeta(fillerItemMeta);

        int inventorySize = (getFunctionalItems().size()>=54) ? 54 : getFunctionalItems().size()+(9-getFunctionalItems().size()%9)*Math.min(1, getFunctionalItems().size()%9);

        inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(player, inventorySize, getName());

        for(int i = 0; i < inventory.getSize(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, fillerItem);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < getFunctionalItems().size(); i++) {
            inventory.setItem(i, getFunctionalItems().get(i));
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        handle(event);
    }

    public abstract ArrayList<ItemStack> getFunctionalItems();

    public abstract String getName();

    protected abstract void handle(InventoryClickEvent event);

    public Material getFiller() {
        return Material.GRAY_STAINED_GLASS_PANE;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    protected final ItemStack createFunctionalItem(String name, Material material) {
        ItemStack itemStack = new ItemStack(material);
        ItemMeta itemMeta = itemStack.getItemMeta();
        itemMeta.setDisplayName(name);
        itemStack.setItemMeta(itemMeta);

        return itemStack;
    }
}
```

In my child class it gets handled like following

```java
    @Override
    public void handle(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        ItemStack clicked = event.getCurrentItem();
        Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();

        MainGUI mainGUI = new MainGUI(player);
        NameGUI nameGUI = new NameGUI(player);
        SkinGUI skinGUI = new SkinGUI(player);

        //Main GUI
        if(Arrays.equals(event.getClickedInventory().getContents(), mainGUI.getInventory().getContents())) {
            switch(clicked.getItemMeta().getDisplayName()) {
                case "Set Name" -> player.openInventory(nameGUI.getInventory());
                case "Set Skin" -> player.openInventory(skinGUI.getInventory());
            }
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
```

But if I test it gets called 2 times on the first click and on the following so many times it even forces my game to crash. I know I can just put in a delay but I really want to know why this is the case.

Thank you

Comment: Consider registering the events outside of the GUI constructors. Your event listener gets registered every time you instantiate a new GUI object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running multiple times because you are adding each new GUI to listener.

For example, here:

```
MainGUI mainGUI = new MainGUI(player);
NameGUI nameGUI = new NameGUI(player);
SkinGUI skinGUI = new SkinGUI(player);
```

You are creating 3 GUIs, so 3 new inventory click event register in listener.

To fix this, I suggest you to :

1. Make ONE class that receive `InventoryClickEvent` event, and call GUI that you be called.

For example, you have a list with all GUI:

```
public static List<GUI> ALL_GUIS = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you should have a way to determine in which inventory the player clicked, such as:

- Inventory name. Not very good solution if this can change, but easier to create and use
- Inventory holder like this:

```
public class MainGUIHolder implements InventoryHolder {

    @Override
    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now use it like that:

```
Inventory mainInv = Bukkit.createInventory(new MainGUIHolder(), 9, "My inv");
```

You can check with `inventory instanceof MainGUIHolder`, then get the holder instance with maybe some object that is currently edited by the player

2. Don't create multiple times GUI instance. For me, it's not a good way, and I think it's better to do like this :

```
MainGUI mainGUI = GuiManager.getMainGUID(); // here get the alone main GUI instance
// now use it
```